# Upgrading .Net 2.0 to .Net 3.5

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, asp.net, .net

Will this require a reboot? Even if I include all the security patches as well.

NB This will not be to .Net 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an upgrade, per se.  Different versions of the .NET framework are a side-by-side install.  Usually it does require a reboot because the 3.5 installer will service pack 2.0 and it's not unusual for something to have 2.0 framework files locked.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an upgrade, they are two different products that can coexist. And yes, it will require a reboot.